# Obtain facebook password hash via API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way of using the facebook API (either C++, Java or C#) to obtain the hash of my facebook password, given I provide my facebook username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and what would you even use it for?

Comment: Very legitimate things, I'm sure